# Custom EndpointMvcAdapter for the management resource in Spring Boot 1.3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In Spring Boot 1.2.6 I had a custom `EndpointMvcAdapter` that got called when I navigated to the management resource exposed at `/admin` (when the `management.context-path` property is set to `/admin`). After upgrading to spring-boot 1.3.7 this `EndpointMvcAdapter` is no longer called when I go to the management resource (`/admin`). Rather a similar (but not exactly the same) JSON document is returned instead that is not using my custom resource (I suppose this is now default in 1.3.x and in 1.2.x there was no such resource available). My `EndpointMvcAdapter` looks like this:

```
@Component
public class EndpointsMvcEndpoint extends EndpointMvcAdapter {

    private final EndpointsEndpoint delegate;

    @Value("${management.context-path}")
    private String managementContextPath;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointsMvcEndpoint(EndpointsEndpoint delegate) {
        super(delegate);
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Set<EndpointResource> filter(@RequestParam(required = false) Boolean enabled,
                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean sensitive) {

        Predicate<Endpoint> isEnabled = endpoint -> matches(endpoint::isEnabled, ofNullable(enabled));
        Predicate<Endpoint> isSensitive = endpoint -> matches(endpoint::isSensitive, ofNullable(sensitive));

        return this.delegate.invoke().stream()
                .filter(isEnabled.and(isSensitive))
                .map(endpoint -> new EndpointResource(endpoint, managementContextPath))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private <T> boolean matches(Supplier<T> supplier, Optional<T> value) {
        return !value.isPresent() || supplier.get().equals(value.get());
    }
}
```

and `EndpointResource` looks like this:

```
class EndpointResource extends ResourceSupport {

        private final Endpoint endpoint;

        EndpointResource(Endpoint endpoint, String managementContextPath) {
            this.endpoint = endpoint;
            if (!endpoint.isEnabled()) {
                return;
            }
             .....
            this.add(new Link(path, endpoint.getId()));
        }
}
```

and the `EndpointsEndpoint` class looks like this:

```
@Component
class EndpointsEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint<List<Endpoint>> {

    private List<Endpoint> endpoints;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointsEndpoint(List<Endpoint> endpoints) {
        super("/");
        this.endpoints = endpoints;
    }


    @Override
    public List<Endpoint> invoke() {
        return endpoints;
    }
}
```

How can I re-enable my custom management context landing page in spring-boot 1.3.x?